# Integrate Camunda or other workflow designer with Website seemlessly

Tags: html, workflow, camunda

We want to create visual DAG workflow designer in our website. We found [Camunda](https://camunda.com/) a good interface which can design BPM flowcharts. However, the documentation shows that we need to design workflow independently in Camunda designer.

Is there any way we can show designer in our website, in a way that designer looks like our website part, rather than a separate webpage itself?

If you can suggest any other better alternative to Camunda, we are open to explore. What we have seen, there is a lot of workflow engines available [here](https://github.com/meirwah/awesome-workflow-engines), but not sure which one fits the need.

Answer (score 0):

The Camunda modeler is basically Electron wrapped around https://bpmn.io/. You can use bpmn-js to include modelling functionality in your own page. It is as simple as shown on the bpmn.io website:

```
<script>
  var viewer = new BpmnJS({ container: 'body' });

  viewer.importXML(bpmnXML, function(err) {

    if (err) {
      console.log('error rendering', err);
    } else {
      console.log('we are good!');
    }
  });
</script>
```